# What is the fastest way to fill up the free space on a disk in C?

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite

I need a way to fill up the remaining free disk space on a drive with zeros (zero the free apace so that the virtual hard disk don't take space for useless data).

I want speed since the space to fill can be several GB big and I need to use the smallest memory footprint since this will be used in a "vintage" (think 486 with 4MB RAM) environment.

I was thinking to create a file with `fopen` and fill it with zeros with `fwrite` and finally delete the file but it seem less than optimal...

I'm not used to write pure C and I'm using a relic compiler (Borland Turbo C 2.01). This is just a fun project to better understand C and at the same time make a small utility for my relic MS-DOS (virtual) environment.

Can you tell me if there is a better way than using `fwrite` to achieve this?

This is how my code look like so far (untested):

```
m = malloc(buffSize);
if (!m) {
    return -4;
}
f = fopen(tempFilename, "wb");
if (!f) {
    free(m);
    return -5;
}
i = buffSize;
while (i--) {
    m[i] = 0;
}
written = buffSize;
while (written) {
    written = fwrite(m, buffSize, 1, f);
}
fclose(f);
free(m);
```

Comment: If you're doing this to remove incriminating evidence before giving the computer to someone else, there can still be bits and pieces of old files leftover in the unused space in the last cluster of files. There are tools to clean a disk properly.

Comment: @ooga - I know but it's to zero the free apace so that the virtual hard disk don't take space for useless data. Since this is under a relic OS (MS-DOS 5), I could not find a proper "native" tool do do this so I'm creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fwrite` is probably the fastest way to write things if you restrict yourself to standard C. Be sure to use a large enough all-zero buffer (e.g. 32Kbytes at least). You could use `memset` to clear that buffer (or the older non-standard `bzero`), or you could use `calloc` instead of `malloc` to allocate it.

However, your Borland Turbo C is not a very good and C standard compliant compiler.

Why don't you switch to a more recent compiler and operating system (e.g. some recent Linux and recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/))?

Comment: I want to do this to zero the free apace so that the virtual hard disk don't take space for useless data. I know some tool that can be run on the host machine (opening the virtual hard disk) but I want a "native" solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this (untested)

```
f = fopen(tempFilename, "wb");
fseek(f, buffSize-1, SEEK_SET);
fputc(0, fp);
fclose(f);
```